# Black box covering a part of the Genymotion Console

Tags: genymotion

Genymotion is showing a black box covering a part of the console. Currently, I'm using the latest update as of today (3.0.4).

**Can I fix this issue from my end?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using macos Catalina? There has been an update lately which introduced a compatibility issue with Genymotion current librendr.
This will be solved with Genymotion 3.1. If you don't wish to wait for the stable release, you can try the beta version at https://www.genymotion.com/download-beta/